# word level ngram implementaion for solr >8.0

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, n-gram, solr-search

given word: "ABC regional private coastal area"

(shingle filter factory)tokenization i want: "ABC regional private coastal area", "ABC regional private coastal", "ABC regional private", "ABC regional", "ABC".

results: "ABC regional private coastal area", "ABC regional private coastal","ABC regional", "ABC", "regional" etc..

and some times creates tokenization i want like "regional _ coastal", "regional _ coastal area", "_ coastal"

is there any filter or tokenizer that will help me achieve this result.

already tried:
edgeNGram(character level token-split), Ngram(character level token-split), Shinglefilterfactory(word leveltoken-split).

results:
shingle comes close but it also creates token like
word: "hello world sample"
after tokenization: hello world , world, sample
which gives me unecessary results for both sample and world which i dont need.

Thanks in advance.

use these links to look at the query and results
[Query Performed(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUHHn.png)][Shingle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnLOi.png)][EdgeNGram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeP6Q.png)]

Comment: In your first example you also included `regional` by itself, which is in the same as what you say you don't want in your last example. Do you want the shingles only generated from the start? i.e. `ABC`, `ABC regional`, etc, and nothing starting with anything? Only prefixes of the original string?

Comment: i solved it with custom tokenizer, filter. now its working the way i wanted my tokenizer and filter to work.  Thanks :)